# How does su detect fakeroot?

Tags: root, su, fakeroot

If I run su, it asks for the password of the target user. If i run it as root, it does not ask for a password. But if I run it in fakeroot, how is it possible that it will ask for a password? Should fakeroot not make all programs think that you are root? For my own program, the only way of doing this would be trying to run su, and look at the return code. but how does su do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`su` detects nothing.

From `man fakeroot`:

> fakeroot works by replacing the file manipulation library functions (`chmod(2)`, `stat(2)` etc.) by ones that simulate the effect the real library functions would have had, had the user really been root.
> These wrapper functions are in a shared  library  `/usr/lib/*/libfake‐root-\*.so` or similar location on your platform.  The shared object is loaded through the `LD_PRELOAD` mechanism of the dynamic loader. (See `ld.so(8)`)

`su`, being a setuid executable, always runs as root - but doesn't care about `LD_PRELOAD`¹. So, while "normal" programs are being told they're run as root by replacing the functions with which they ask for that, `su` never sees that modification. So, `su` just runs as usual.

---

¹ that would be a terrible security hole; you could just set `LD_PRELOAD` to contain a library that does whatever you want to be done, and it would automatically be executed as root if you could run *any* setuid executable

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `fakeroot` (see `man fakeroot`) seems to answer this for you:

> **DESCRIPTION** `fakeroot` runs a command in an environment wherein it  appears  to  have root  privileges  for  file  manipulation.

and,

> **EXAMPLES** Only the effects that user `joost` could do anyway happen for real

and finally,

> **SECURITY ASPECTS** `fakeroot` is a regular, non-setuid program. It does not enhance a user's privileges, or decrease the system's security.

In the first block, note the word *appears*. In the examples extract, consider the user `joost` to be you. In the final section, there's a clear statement that `fakeroot` does not add privileges or decrease security in any way. Specifically, this means that it does not change how the real `su` works.